# counting all string values in given column of a table and grouping it based on third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, querying

I have three columns. the table looks like this:

```
ID.   names     tag
1.     john.     1
2.     sam       0
3.    sam,robin. 1
4.     robin.    1
```

Id: type integer
Names: type string
Tag: type integer (just 0,1)

What I want is to find how many times each name is repeated grouped by 0 and 1. this is to be done in python.

Answer must look like

```
               0                 1
John           23                12
Robin          32                10
sam            9                 30
```

Comment: Are those names separated by commas in a list `['sam', 'robin.']` or is it the string `'sam,robin.'`?

Comment: I cannot understand the expected output. How count for John is 23? and what is 12?

Comment: It's just an example assuming that for a given full input (not 4 rows) john would happen to pop up 23 times with tag=1 and 12 times with tag=0

Comment: @ALollz well those are strings separated by semicolon (;)

Comment: @mad_  yes user-thunderwood is right. it's just an example. we need how many times those names are getting repeated for each of the two tags.

Comment: Then you need to provide a [mcve] that represents your data. Otherwise, you're going to get a solution to the problem you posted, not the problem you're having. If there's a semicolon between the values, then there should be a semicolon in your example.

Comment: @ALollz sorry for teh confusion. I ahve edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `extractall` and `crosstab`:

```
s = df.names.str.extractall(r'(\w+)').reset_index(1, drop=True).join(df.tag)

pd.crosstab(s[0], s['tag'])
```

```
tag    0  1
0
john   0  1
robin  0  2
sam    1  1
```

Comment: yup this works. I mistyped it. Thank you so much. This is a much concise answer.

Comment: This separates everything including ones separated by slashes and space. CAn we limit the separating entity to just the semicolon (;)?

Comment: It's not clear how you know how to group `John A/John Adams` with `John A`. That makes this a *much* more complicated problem.  I rolled back your question because you shouldn't edit it after you already have answers, but you should ask a new question with your new requirements.

Comment: Ohk. I did not know this. I am bit new here. So the changed question also works for me. under that scenario, and keeping your answer in mind, is there any way where i can control teh separation to just " ; " and no other things?

Comment: You could create `s` using something like `s = df.names.str.extractall(r'([^;.]+)')[0].str.strip().reset_index(1, drop=True).to_frame().join(df.tag)`

Comment: But remember, this won't understand what `John A`, and `John A/John Adams` are referring to the same value.

Comment: Thank you.This solved a major part of my problem. I can do it form there. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the nature of your `names` column, there is some re-processing that needs to be done before you can get value counts. In the case of your example dataframe, this could look something like:

```
my_counts = (df.set_index(['ID.', 'tag'])
             # Get rid of periods and split on commas
             .names.str.strip('.').str.split(',')
             .apply(pd.Series)
             .stack()
             .reset_index([0, 1])
             # rename column 0 for consistency, easier reading
             .rename(columns={0: 'names'})
             # Get value counts of names per tag:
             .groupby('tag')['names']
             .value_counts()
             .unstack('tag', fill_value=0))

>>> my_counts
tag    0  1
names      
john   0  1
robin  0  2
sam    1  1
```

Comment: pandas data frames does not have a names attribute. So I could not verify your solution

Comment: Also some names are like 

John A/John adams ; Sam
John ; robin
john

thus if we remove everything wont it give me wrong asnwer

Comment: for your first comment, what is the output of `df.columns`? Because your dataframe clearly appears to have a `names` column. And for your second, you'll have to provide an example which actually represents your cases. The code above provides the solution I posted for the dataframe you supplied. We cannot infer the different kind of structure you have in your `names` column.

Comment: oh Sorry my bad. My dataframe contains "names" as a column name but when we write df.names , it shows names is not an attribute of dataframe. Also when I write df.columns, it shows me list of column names which is ['id', 'names','tag']

Comment: I got an error:
" 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_counts'"